# How to setState with an object in Typescript? [Error ts(2345)]

Tags: reactjs, typescript

### Interface

```
interface Info {
    name: string,
    brand?: string,
    category?: string,
    subCategory?: string
}
```

### useState

```
const   [info, setInfo]     =   useState<Info | null>(null);
```

---

I'm able to successfully set the state of the name input

```
onChange={e => setInfo({...info,name:e.target.value.toLowerCase()})}
```

but for any other property of the Info object, I get an error.

```
onChange={e => setInfo({...info,category:e.target.value.toLowerCase()})}
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Argument of type '{ category: any; name?: string | undefined; brand?: string | undefined; subCategory?: string | undefined; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<Info | null>'.
  Type '{ category: any; name?: string | undefined; brand?: string | undefined; subCategory?: string | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'Info'.
    Types of property 'name' are incompatible.
      Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
        Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)
```

I get that this error is happening because the name field is compulsory & each setState call is expected to have the name property. Knowing that, how do I resolve this error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the `as` keyword:

```
onChange={e => setInfo({...info,category:e.target.value.toLowerCase()} as Info)}
```

Comment: 'Type assertion' did solve my error, but I was wondering if there is a better/correct way to structure my code or types in order to avoid this situation?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening due to the fact that `e.target.value.toLowerCase()` might be returning `undefined` and the `name` type is set to `string`.

Either do -
`onChange={e => setInfo({...info,category:e.target.value.toLowerCase() || ''})}`

OR

update your type definition to -

```
interface Info {
    name: string | undefined,
    brand?: string,
    category?: string,
    subCategory?: string
}
```